# Is there a way to make different bootstrap file for different modules using ZEND framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Right now I am using ZF1 and I don't want to load functions which are associated with different module at the time of initiation. I would like to make different bootstrap file for that.

[image]

The common bootstrap file extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make different bootstrap file for different modules using ZEND framework 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007908/is-there-a-way-to-make-different-bootstrap-file-for-different-modules-using-zend)

Answer (score 1):

Each module may have its own `bootstrap.php` file. Change the class definition to:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
```

Where `Admin` is the name of your module folder.

You can now have an independent bootstrap for this module.